# How to access UITableViewCell object without creating *Cell.swift-file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have tableView with dynamic cells.

In the `tableViewCell` I have `2 labels` and `1 button`

In function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm adding action to it's button by such string of code:

```
btn?.addTarget(self, action: "downloadButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And of course I have this function

```
func downloadButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject){

}
```

In this function I can access button of it's Cell by

```
(sender as UIButton)?.hidden = true //for example
```

But how can I access these **labels** from this function - `downloadButtonClicked`?

They have specific tag values but I do not know how to access them. A lot of variants with implementing "`viewWithTag`" did not satisfied me

I need the variant without creating specific file "`MyTableViewCell`.swift" for this cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the button index first like this:

```
var btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPos)!
```

Then create cell using indexPath that we just got

```
 cell  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourTableViewCellClass
```

Then you can access your label using

```
 cell.yourLabel.text = "anything"
```

Comment: what if we use custom Label or button?